# How do I define HAVE_STDIO_H in VC++ 2005?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I just built an updated version of SDL.dll, an open-source C DLL that my Delphi project uses, with the Express edition of Visual C++ 2005.  I dropped it in the folder with my EXE and tried to run it, but it won't load:

```
The procedure entry point SDL_RWFromFP could not be located in the dynamic
link library SDL.dll.
```

Now C never was my strong point, but I remember enough of it from college to try and track this one down. I went poking around in the source code to see what had happened to this function, and I found it grayed out, beneath a preprocessor directive:

```
#ifdef HAVE_STDIO_H
```

IIRC, STDIO is the standard C I/O library.  I assume this means that it's not available. Anyone know why that would be and how to fix it?  Is this a Visual C++ issue or an SDL one?

Comment: Please confirm that you have unzipped and used VisualC.zip as per VisualC.html, both found in the SDL source archive.

Comment: What visualc.zip?  You must be looking at a different archive than I am.  I've got visualc.html, but no visualc.zip and no reference to it in the html.  I'm using the latest snapshot of the SDL 1.3 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most often in the Unix/Linux world, names like `HAVE_STDIO_H` indicate that the code has been 'autoconfiscated' (which is the official term used to describe the state of having been made to work with the 'autotools' such as 'autoconf').  In such a set up, the configure process would determine whether `<stdio.h>` was available and would set `#define HAVE_STDIO_H 1` in the `config.h` file that it generates.  The compilation would then discover that the platform has `<stdio.h>` and would compile the matching code (the stuff that is currently greyed out).

Adapting to your Windows environment, somewhat less than 100% confidently since there could be some other significance to `HAVE_STDIO_H` on Windows, you might decide that it would be OK to include `-DHAVE_STDIO_H` in the command line options when you run the compiler.  Or you might create the config file by hand, and define `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H` (which is the normal way to indicate that configuration settings are in the file 'config.h').  In the 'config.h' file, you'd have `#define HAVE_STDIO_H 1` as mentioned above.

---

Note: on Unix, you normally find a shell script called 'configure' which you run to create the config.h file.  If you have Cygwin, there's an outside chance that you can use that script on Windows - I've just checked that an autoconfiscated package I created on Solaris was configurable on Windows under Cygwin and it mostly worked - all except some network handling.  I'd not guarantee that it will always fail (but it's software - guaranteeing anything is pretty dangerous).  I should add that the problem is in my auto-configuration code (the tests for the network functionality clearly aren't quite correct), and not in Cygwin per se.  If I'd done the job properly, it would have worked.  (Someone said "There is no portable code; there is only code that has been ported".  That applies here.)

You do need a good simulation of a Unix environment.  MingW might also work.

Answer (score 1):

What do the preprocessor directives above it do?

Most likely, this is simply for determining some properties of your compiler, and it's greyed out because whatever the macro signifies, does not apply to your compiler.

Your problem is most likely elsewhere.

Since it can't find the function `SDL_RWFromFP`, you should probably see if that function is for some reason disabled by a preprocessor directive as well.

However, my guess is that the function exists, but does not get marked as __declspec( dllexport )

Without that, it won't get exposed so programs loading the DLL can call it. Most likely you have to #define something to specify that you want to create a DLL, which will enable the necessary preprocessor magic to insert the dllexport part in front of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should not have to add any HAVE_STDIO_H: those are not meant to be public anyway (although sadly many projects pollute the public namespace with those).

I would guess you did not build SDL correctly - or that Visual studio 2005 is not well supported by SDL (I don't know much about SDL, so those are really wild guesses without much information). Is there any test suite for SDL, such as you can test the built dll ?